# Let $(10)$ be the subgroup of $\langle R^+,*\rangle $ generated by 10,Prove that $R^+/(10)$ $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}/Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(10)$ be the subgroup of $\langle\mathbb{R}^+,*\rangle$ generated by 10,Prove that $\mathbb{R}^+/(10)$ $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

In this question ,I don't how to find the isomorphism which take the 1 to 0 without other number over the size.
Please give me some help .

Comment: What is $Z$ here?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Comment: @azif00 Sorry, that is integer,I have fixed it.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thanks!!and apology for my first use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $x \mapsto \log_{10}(x)$.  It takes $1$ to $0$, turns multiplication into addition, and takes the powers of $10$ to the integers, which is what you want.

Comment: Could it maintain one to one ? Like Log_10 (0.1)=0=Log_10 (1) in mod Z?

Comment: That's fine because $0.1$ and $1$ are equivalent after modding out by $(10)$.  If the map is called $\phi$, you can check that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $x = 10^n y$, i.e. if and only if $x = y$ in $\mathbb{R}^+/(10)$.

Comment: Oh,I miss the negative power.I got it,Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+/(10)$ where $\phi(x)$ is the equivalence class of $10^x$.

Comment: I got it,thank for your answer